# Find records in the same table matching multiple criteria

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite table containing metadata extracted from thousands of audio files in a directory tree.  The objective of the extraction is to run a series of queries against the table to identify and rectify anomalies in the underlying metadata.  The corrected metadata is then written back from the table to the underlying files. The underlying files are grouped into albums with each album in a directory of its own.  Table structure relevant to my question is as follows:

- __path: unique identifier being the path and source filename combined
- __dirpath: in simple terms represents the directory from which the file represented by a table record was drawn.  Records making up an album will have the same __dirpath
- __discnumber: number designating the disc number from which the track originates.  The field can be blank or contain a string 1,2,3... etc.

I'd like to identify all records where (__dirpath is identical and __discnumber equals 1).

Comment: and so far, you've tried...?

Comment: I've managed to return the unique __dirpath entries using: SELECT __dirpath,count(*) FROM audio GROUP BY __dirpath HAVING count(*)>0

Comment: A little stuck re how to combine that with the __discnumber criterion.

Comment: anyone have any further insights to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT __dirpath,
                discnumber
  FROM alib
 WHERE __dirpath IN (
           SELECT __dirpath
             FROM alib
            GROUP BY __dirpath
           HAVING count( * ) > 0
       )
AND 
       discnumber = 1
 ORDER BY __dirpath,
          discnumber;
```